# C# : Unable to obtain Accesstoken. Google calendar API

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, oauth-2.0

Hello I'm trying to use the google calendar API.  I'm unable to obtain an access token.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
  private string ObtainAccessToken(string code)
    {
        string content =
                         "code=" + code + "&" +
                        "client_id=1016429729591.apps.googleusercontent.com&"+ 
                        "client_secret={MySecret}&" +
                        "redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&" +
                        "grant_type=authorization_code";//authorization_code";
        Google.Apis.Authentication.HttpRequestFactory
                factory = new Google.Apis.Authentication.HttpRequestFactory();


        HttpWebRequest req = factory.Create(new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?"+content), "POST");
        byte[] data = Google.Apis.Utilities.EncodeStringToUtf8(content);
        req.ContentLength = data.Length;

        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

   req.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        req.GetResponse();
    }
```

The api documentation I'm following is here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

I'm constantly getting HTTP Bad Request 400 error.

I have tried the solution given in this question but it doesn't work either:
[Google Calendar API - Bad Request (400) Trying To Swap Code For Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632803/google-calendar-api-bad-request-400-trying-to-swap-code-for-access-token)

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this sample: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tasks.SimpleOAuth2/Program.cs?repo=samples

It is a command-line app that uses OAuth 2.0 to authorize Tasks API requests, it should be very easy to adapt it to consume the Calendar API instead.