# Bad Request Getting Google Access Token

Tags: .net, access-token, bad-request

When I do a simple web request  to this URL using the the WebClient Object (or any standard HTTP request method using the .NET framework), I get a 400 Bad Request Error.  When I tried with CURL, I get a valid response from the web server.  It seems like Google doesn't like a windows request - something throws it off.

It works in https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and it also works if I just create a web form and do a post - I get an access token back no problem.

But I do need to be able to do it programmatically. 
I also tried WebRequest and HTTP object but did not really have a luck working with them yet.

I found about 4-5 similar questions here and some of them have a code examples - I tried their code but had no luck. 
[(Code that I have tried)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632803/google-calendar-api-bad-request-400-trying-to-swap-code-for-access-token)

Function GetAccessToken(ByVal Code As String, ByVal sScopes As String) As ActionResult
    Dim sAccessURLTokenURL As String = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"

```
Dim oWebCLient As New WebClient

Dim oNameValueCollection As New NameValueCollection

Dim oResponse() As Byte

oWebCLient.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")

oNameValueCollection.Add("client_id", "562344623411-b2mt2215qdfs34asdqwe345jmq2ec7su.apps.googleusercontent.com")
oNameValueCollection.Add("client_secret", "KjsPkBUTosdeROuVfkKBaAwm")
oNameValueCollection.Add("code", Code)
oNameValueCollection.Add("scopes", sScopes)
oNameValueCollection.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code")

oResponse = oWebCLient.UploadValues(sAccessURLTokenURL, oNameValueCollection)

End Function
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Update

Got it to work!

Will Clean Up The Code And Post It With Some Explanations

Comment: If those are your real client id and secret, you should reseed them.

Comment: Thanks Eric - these are not real. They are the same length though. Good looking out, sir!

Comment: Very good!  I tend to see lots of people post sensitive information on SO, one of the worst places to do so.

Comment: 100% agree with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Imports System.Text

Public Class OAuth2Utilities

Protected msTokenAuthorizationURL As String = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"

Public Function ExchangeAuthorizationCodeForTokens(ByVal oAuth2Model As oAuth2Model) As String
    Dim oWebResponse As WebResponse
    Dim sWebResponse As String

    If Not oAuth2Model Is Nothing Then

        oWebResponse = GetWebResponse(oAuth2Model)

        If Not oWebResponse Is Nothing Then

            sWebResponse = ReadWebResponse(oWebResponse)

        End If

    End If

    Return sWebResponse
End Function

Protected Function GetWebResponse(ByVal oAuth2Model As oAuth2Model) As WebResponse
    Dim oWebResponse As WebResponse = Nothing

    Dim oWebRequest As WebRequest

    Dim sRequestParameters As String
    Dim oRequestParametersByteArray() As Byte

    Dim oUTF8Encoding As New UTF8Encoding()

    Dim oStream As Stream

    If Not oAuth2Model Is Nothing Then

        oWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(msTokenAuthorizationURL)

        oWebRequest.Method = "POST"
        oWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

        sRequestParameters = String.Format("code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri={3}&grant_type=authorization_code", oAuth2Model.AuthorizationCode, oAuth2Model.ClientID, oAuth2Model.ClientSecret, oAuth2Model.RedirectURI)

        oRequestParametersByteArray = oUTF8Encoding.GetBytes(sRequestParameters)

        If oRequestParametersByteArray.Length > 0 Then

            oWebRequest.ContentLength = oRequestParametersByteArray.Length

            oStream = oWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
            oStream.Write(oRequestParametersByteArray, 0, oRequestParametersByteArray.Length)

            If Not oStream Is Nothing Then

                oWebResponse = oWebRequest.GetResponse()

            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return oWebResponse
End Function

Protected Function ReadWebResponse(ByVal oWebResponse As WebResponse) As String
    Dim sWebResponse As String = String.Empty

    Dim oStream As Stream
    Dim oStreamReader As StreamReader

    Try

        If IsNothing(oWebResponse) = False Then

            oStream = oWebResponse.GetResponseStream()

            If IsNothing(oStream) = False Then

                oStreamReader = New StreamReader(oStream)

                If Not oStreamReader Is Nothing Then

                    oStreamReader = New StreamReader(oStream)

                    If IsNothing(oStreamReader) = False Then

                        sWebResponse = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()

                    End If

                End If

            End If

        End If

    Catch oException As Exception

    End Try

    Return sWebResponse
End Function

End Class
```

Got it to work. He is what the problem was, folks. I would generate the Authorization Code and would play with it for hours trying to see what I keep getting bad request.

The thing is (special thanks to [Rich Sutton's Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/google-oauth-refresh-token-is-not-being-received)) that once you does not seem to be able to get the **Access Token** / **Refresh Token** using the same Authorization Code after the initial time of doing that.

Here is your friend by the way - [Google OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

Otherwords:

1. You go generate the Authorization Code by putting together a URL passing ClientID, ClientSecret and Redirect URI (plus whatever parameters you want to pass)
2. If you data is You Will Get Back An Authorization Code

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should set method and content type because the server response indicates that: bad request. So, I guess setting content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8`and method to `POST` will work. To do that:

```
oWebCLient.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")
oWebClient.UploadValues(sAccessURLTokenURL, "POST", oNameValueCollection)
```

Webclient, as far as I know, uses `GET` as default method so I think is the problem you are facing... Could you try it please?

**UPDATE**

Also try:

```
oWebClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
oWebClient.Proxy = Nothign
```

Content type is not neede to be set if you use `UploadValues`because it will be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` automatically. It's not clear in docs that charset can be set through headers. Also if Google server detect an invalid parameter automatically will return a Bad Request so you probably have an error in parameters or calling uri, Could you please paste full code that doesn't works? Maybe I could be able to help you better.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It still returning bad request 400. I can do it with Curl Or WebForm as well as some online POST tools and it works just fine and gets it - I believe there is something little that does not let me accomplish it. Will keep trying!

Comment: Updated, sorry for the delay!

Comment: Thanks again! I think I got it now! I appreciate your effort and your help, sir!

Comment: If you found a solution it's great! Thanks to you and sorry to not helped as I would. :)